# What is rep cap in the hats in winter bash

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, winter-bash-2012

What is "rep cap" in the [Just Jesting](http://winterba.sh/just-jesting) hat in [winter bash](http://winterba.sh/)?

How to win it?

Comment: There is no rep cap. You just need to do the things that are pointed out underneath each item

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: @Pekka - in the descriptions, it mentions rep cap. I believe that this is what sfah was referring to :)

Comment: I think we need to earn just 200 reputation to earn this instead of rep cap. [See this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159225/187824)

Comment: When in doubt about any term, refer to the [glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms). Rep cap is mentioned there as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rep cap, is the threshold for reputation.  You can not get more that 200 reputation from votes in a single day.

Comment: I think we should get rid of this.

Comment: Whitout the repcap some people wouldn't have a life outside of stackexchange.

Comment: That's not bad. Higher user activity means less time to get an answer.

Comment: Great irony, this answer just pushed me onto the rep cap.

Comment: I hit the rep cap 2 days ago, before Winter Bash :(

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe : when i get my upvotes reputation back?

Answer (score 2):

Rep cap means you can only earn 200 rep/day from upvote .. note that accept and bounty isn't counted.

But I suspect you will get the rep cap hat on just reaching 200 rep/day check this question

[Just Jesting! awarded before hitting rep cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159225/just-jesting-awarded-before-hitting-rep-cap)